# Lectura de arreglo se hace al reves

Tags: c++

estoy haciendo un código en c++ que debe encontrar si las palabras de un arreglo Palabras se encuentran en un arreglo Diccionario y devolver si la palabra está y en qué posiciones. Para esto hice este código:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 5
 * En
 * Casa
 * De
 * Lalo
 * Casa
 * 4
 * En
 * Casa
 * Lalo
 * Los
 */

struct estado{
    string palabra;
    string esta = "NOESTA";
    int posicion[3] = {-1, -1,-1};
};

void verifica(string palabras[], string dict[], int n, int m, estado encontrado[]);
int main(){
    string palabras[100];
    string diccionario[100];
    estado encontrado[100];
    int n, m;
    cout<<"Ingrese numero de palabras en la frase: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese palabra de la frase: ";
        cin>>palabras[i];
    }

    cout<<"Ingrese numero de palabras en el diccionario: ";
    cin>>m;
    for(int i = 0; i< m; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese palabra del diccionario: ";
        cin>>diccionario[i];
    }

    verifica(palabras,diccionario,n,m,encontrado);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cout << "Palabra: " << encontrado[i].palabra << ", Estado: " << encontrado[i].esta;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                cout << ", Posicion: " << encontrado[i].posicion[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void verifica(string palabras[], string dict[], int n, int m, estado encontrado[]){
    for(int i = 0; i<m; i++){
        encontrado[i].palabra = palabras[i];
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            if(dict[i]==palabras[j]){
                encontrado[i].esta = "ESTA";
                for(int k = 0; k<3; k++){
                    if(encontrado[i].posicion[k] == -1){
                        encontrado[i].posicion[k] = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para este enunciado:
Büsqueda
Se quiere buscar unas palabras en un diccionario para este fin se cuenta con una serie de palabras almacenadas en el
vector palabras de tamano n, una palabra puede repetirse måximo 3 veces.
Adicionalmente se cuenta con una lista de palabras ya definidas en un vector diccionario, contra las cuales se va a
comparar cada palabra de la frase por verificar. El vector diccionario tiene tarnafio m.
Usted debe crear una funciön que verifique si una palabra se encuentra o no en el diccionario. Como resultado de la
verificaciön la funciön genera un arreglo de estructuras estado que debe contener la palabra de la frase, el estado de
la verificaciön, y la posiciön donde se encuentra la palabra en el vector palabras, si la palabra no se encuentra debe
colocar la posiciön de la palabra representado con un valor negativo. En este vector estado que se crea no puede
existir una palabra mås de una vez.
Cada palabra de la frase tendrå un estado de verificaciön como resultado de la comparaciön contra el dccionario. EI
estado de la verificaciön puede ser una de las siguientes opciones:
"ESTA" si la palabra coincide exactamente con alguna del
diccionario
"NOESTA" si la palabra no aparece en el diccionario.

El cual testeé con el comentario que sale al principio. Y el resultado fue este:
[image: Ejemplo]

Está bien en las primeras dos palabras, sin embargo confunde las dos últimas, ya que dice que "De" está en la posición 3 y que "Lalo" no está. Esto mientras "Lalo" se encuentra en la 3 y "De" no está.
Aquí un ejemplo visual de como debería quedar:
[image: Ejemplo]

Answer (score 1):

Has intercambiado los índices:

```
if(dict[i]==palabras[j])
```

Debería ser:

```
if(dict[j]==palabras[i])
```

---

> ahora sólo me devuelve la primera posición de casa, y me dice que Lalo está en la posición 2, cuando debería ser 3.

Realmente esa parte nunca te ha funcionado. Tienes un jaleo de índices y de datos.

Para empezar, es un error usar letras sueltas tipo `m` o `n` como parámetros de entrada de una función, ya que no dan idea de qué es lo que contienen ... y eso hace que el código sea más dificil de leer y de entender.

Otra cosa que no tiene sentido es que pretendas que un registro de `encontrado` pueda almacenar hasta 3 posiciones y, sin embargo, el último bucle de `main` asuma que ese array va a tener tantos elementos como palabras ha introducido el usuario.

Echa un vistazo a esta versión:

```
   int total_encontrado = verifica(palabras,diccionario,n,m,encontrado);

    for (int i = 0; i < total_encontrado; i++)
    {
        cout << "Palabra: " << encontrado[i].palabra << ", Estado: " << encontrado[i].esta;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                cout << ", Posicion: " << encontrado[i].posicion[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

...

int verifica(string palabras[], string dict[], int n, int m, estado encontrado[]){
    int total_encontrado = 0;
    for( int palabraIndex=0; palabraIndex < n; palabraIndex++)
    {
        string const& palabra = palabras[palabraIndex];
        
        for (int estadoIndex=0; estadoIndex<100; estadoIndex++)
        {
            if (encontrado[estadoIndex].palabra == "" || encontrado[estadoIndex].palabra == palabra)
            {
                estado & registro = encontrado[estadoIndex];
                if (estadoIndex > total_encontrado) total_encontrado = estadoIndex;
                
                if (registro.palabra == "")
                    registro.palabra = palabra;
    
                for (int dictIndex=0; dictIndex<m; dictIndex++)
                {
                    if (dict[dictIndex] == palabra)
                    {
                        registro.esta = "ESTA";
                        for (int& posicion: registro.posicion)
                        {   
                            if (posicion == -1)
                            {
                                posicion = palabraIndex;
                                break;
                            }
                        }    
                        break;
                    }                
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo ideal sería dividir este código en funciones, para que al menos sea legible

Comment: Ha servido, sin embargo ahora sólo me devuelve la primera posición de casa, y me dice que Lalo está en la posición 2, cuando debería ser 3.

Comment: @JuanFelipeRubiano Date cuenta que en los arrays, la primera posición tiene índice 0. Tu código no está dando la posición sino el valor del índice. Para obtener la posición (desde la perspectiva del usuario) debes sumar 1 a ese valor.

Comment: Si, entiendo esa parte. El problema es que solo me muestra la primera posición de Casa. Debería decir que está en la 1 y 4. Sin embargo solo muestra que está en la 1.

Comment: @JuanFelipeRubiano esa parte nunca te ha funcionado